# App not deployed on mule standalone server with batch processing

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I deploy mule app on standalone server.In my mule app i used batch processing.
I got following error

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex
-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'batch:execute'. On
e of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "h
ttp://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www
.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http:
//www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
        at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(Defa
ultMuleApplication.java:197) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactW
rapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifa
ctClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrappe
r.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifa
ctDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(Default
ArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
```

Do I need to configure any jar related to batch?
How can I solve this problem?
I need to deploy my mule app on mule standalone server
Please help me to solve this problem..

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This batch module should already be part of the Enterprise standalone server runtime in the lib/mule folder: mule-module-batch-ee-3.8.0.jar. It looks like you might be using Community Edition Standalone runtime that will not support enterprise modules.